# Django Haystack update index only for 1 model

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I am currently trying out Django haystack to update data from PostgreSQL to a solr collection.

So, I have defined 2 models in `search_indexes.py`. So, when I run the command `python manage.py update_index` it indexes the data from both the models defined in `search_indexes.py` to my solr collection.

HOW DO I PERFORM `update_index` OPERATION ONLY FOR A SPECIFIC MODEL THAT I NEED?

Currently, when I run the command, the following 2 models ran.

```
Indexing 2 model1
Indexing 12 model2
```

`search_indexes.py`

```
from haystack import indexes
from .models import table1, table2

class model1(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(
        document=True,
        use_template=True,
        template_name="search/indexes/tenants/table1_text.txt"
    )
    ats_id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='ats_id')
    ats_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='ats_name')
    added_by = indexes.CharField(model_attr='added_by')
    added_on = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='added_on')

    def get_model(self):
        return table1

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

class model2(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(
        document=True,
        use_template=True,
        template_name="search/indexes/tenants/table2_text.txt"
    template_id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='template_id')
    template_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='template_name')
    aspect = indexes.CharField(model_attr='aspect')
    version = indexes.CharField(model_attr='version')
    added_by = indexes.CharField(model_attr='added_by')
    added_on = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='added_on')
    ats_id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='ats_id')

    def get_model(self):
        return table2

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Please suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Update just a single model (in a complex app).
./manage.py update_index models.model1
```

[docs to update_index](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/management_commands.html#update-index)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However it's happening twice `Indexing 12 model2` is printed two times. any suggestion please how to avoid this?

Comment: Could you run this with `--verbosity=2` and write what is printed out?

Comment: `Indexing 12 model1
  indexed 1 - 12 of 12 (worker PID: 1610863).
Indexing 12 model1
  indexed 1 - 12 of 12 (worker PID: 1610863).
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down`

Comment: My bad, I have defined two collections in `HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS` which is why this is happening. I have kept only `default` now and its happening only once.

one last doubt - Is there a way to define mapping such that a models data get indexed into a mapped collection? I mean, where should I mention that mapping? without mapping, the data from all the models defined in search_indexes.py is getting dumped to all collections in solr. for example, i have 5 models and I have 5 collections in solr. So, I wanted this 5 models data to go into respective mapped collections.